# Why the training time of CRF module from allennlp is higher?

Tags: pytorch, bert-language-model, allennlp, crf

I have build a custom Model in pytorch with a BERT + BiLSTM + CRF architecture. For the CRF layer I have used the allennlp's CRF module. Due to the CRF module the training and inference time increases highly.

As far as I know the CRF layer should not increase the training time a lot. Can someone help with this issue.

I have tried training with and without the CRF. It looks like the CRF takes more time.

Comment: The time complexity of the forward-backward algorithm (which AllenNLP's CRF implementation uses) is O(L^2T), where L is the number of labels, and T is the sequence length. How many labels do you have?

Comment: I have around 11 labels.

Also do you think there is a problem with their implementation that it does not use GPU at it's complete potential?